# i want an alert if the results are far apart

Tags: javascript, html

my table can calculate the average but i want to add an alert with this condition,
1.if the difference between input1 and input 2(that is input1 - input2) is greater than 0.3(an alert should popup saying "NOT REPEATABLE."
But if the results are close to each other (that is if input1 - input2 is less than or equal to 0.3),no alert must be displayed.

NB:the table should keep on calculating the average but i want to add that feature discribed above.
HOW DO I ADD THAT ALERT ON MY CODE BELOW.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>calculate</title>
    </head>
    <script>     
        const reducer=(a,c)=>a+c;
        const average=(n)=>parseFloat( n.value ) / 2 || 0;


        
        const keyuphandler=(e)=>{
          if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type=='text' ){
        
            let table=e.target.closest('table');
            let tr=e.target.closest('tr');
            
            let group=tr.dataset.group;
            let elem=e.target.dataset.elem;

            let result=table.querySelector(`tr[data-group="${group}"] input[data-elem="${elem}"].result`);
            let inputs=table.querySelectorAll(`tr[data-group="${group}"] input[data-elem="${elem}"].input`);
            
            result.value = [...inputs]
              .map( average )
              .reduce( reducer, 0 )
          }
        };



        document.addEventListener('keyup',keyuphandler);

      </script>
      <style>
        table {
          width: 50px;
          box-sizing:border-box;
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          font-family:monospace
        }
        td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 0px;
          font-size: 10px;
        }
        th {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 0px;
        }
       
        table {
          box-sizing:border-box;
          font-family:monospace
        }
        td,th{padding:0.25rem;}

        [data-elem='carbon']{background:rgba(0,0,100,0.1)}
        [data-elem='sulphur']{background:rgba(0,100,0,0.1)}
        [readonly]{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}

        .input{width:3rem}
        .result{width:3.5rem}
        input{border:1px solid grey;padding:0.2rem;}

      </style>
       <body>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>%<br />Carbon</th>
            <th>Average<br />Carbon</th>
          </tr>
          
          <tr data-group=1>
            <td><input type='text' class='input' data-elem='carbon' placeholder="input1"/></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='result' data-elem='carbon' readonly placeholder="average" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-group=1>
            <td><input type='text' class='input' data-elem='carbon' placeholder="input2" /></td>
            <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </body>
      </table>
</html>
```

Comment: the repeatability should also apply to all the inputs that i am going to add  in all data groups

Comment: You described what you want but not what is causing you a problem doing it.

Comment: Please use a good editor or HTML validator. Your markup has issues. You're missing several closing tags, I think. Also, maybe set your browser's spell checker to English.

Comment: Protip: Don't use `var`. You're already using `let` in many places, so just use that unless you have constant values, which should use `const`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the difference to be interchangeable, you can use the `abs` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>calculate</title>
    </head>
    <script>     
        const reducer=(a,c)=>a+c;
        const average=(n)=>parseFloat( n.value ) / 2 || 0;


        
        const keyuphandler=(e)=>{
          if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type=='text' ){
        
            let table=e.target.closest('table');
            let tr=e.target.closest('tr');
            
            let group=tr.dataset.group;
            let elem=e.target.dataset.elem;

            let result=table.querySelector(`tr[data-group="${group}"] input[data-elem="${elem}"].result`);
            let inputs=table.querySelectorAll(`tr[data-group="${group}"] input[data-elem="${elem}"].input`);
            
            // need to convert to floats first
            const inputFloats = [...inputs].map(inp => parseFloat(inp.value));
            // simple if
            if (Math.abs(inputFloats[0] - inputFloats[1]) > 0.3) {
              alert("NOT REPEATABLE")
            }
            // then you don't need to map again
            result.value = inputFloats.reduce((a,b) => (a + b) || 0) / 2
          }
        };



        document.addEventListener('keyup',keyuphandler);

      </script>
      <style>
        table {
          width: 50px;
          box-sizing:border-box;
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          font-family:monospace
        }
        td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 0px;
          font-size: 10px;
        }
        th {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 0px;
        }
       
        table {
          box-sizing:border-box;
          font-family:monospace
        }
        td,th{padding:0.25rem;}

        [data-elem='carbon']{background:rgba(0,0,100,0.1)}
        [data-elem='sulphur']{background:rgba(0,100,0,0.1)}
        [readonly]{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}

        .input{width:3rem}
        .result{width:3.5rem}
        input{border:1px solid grey;padding:0.2rem;}

      </style>
       <body>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>%<br />Carbon</th>
            <th>Average<br />Carbon</th>
          </tr>
          
          <tr data-group=1>
            <td><input type='text' class='input' data-elem='carbon' placeholder="input1"/></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='result' data-elem='carbon' readonly placeholder="average" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-group=1>
            <td><input type='text' class='input' data-elem='carbon' placeholder="input2" /></td>
            <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </body>
      </table>
</html>
```